# Who is Mukhayriq "The best of jews"?

Tags: history

I've found one article on this subject on [islamicity](https://www.islamicity.org/21483/the-rabbi-who-prophet-muhammad-called-the-best-of-jews/).

This article states many things, that I could list one by one on here.

However, it would be easier for all reading this in the future, if someone just gives us a description with islamic sources on who this man was in relation to Prophet Muhammad (PBUH).

Note: I found no mention of this Jewish Rabbi at all on stack-exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is mentioned briefly in works of Seerah:

> قال ابن إسحاق: وكان ممن قتل يوم أحد مخيريق وكان أحد بني ثعلبة بن الفطيون، فلما كان يوم أحد قال: يا معشر يهود، والله لقد علمتم أن نصر محمد عليكم لحق. قالوا: إن اليوم يوم السبت. قال: لا سبت لكم. فأخذ سيفه وعدته وقال: إن أصبت فمالي لمحمد يصنع فيه ما شاء. ثم غدا إلى
>
> رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم فقاتل معه حتى قتل. فقال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم فيما بلغنا: مخيريق خير يهود
>
> قال السهيلي: فجعل رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم أموال مخيريق - وكانت سبع حوائط - أوقافا بالمدينة. قال محمد بن كعب القرظي: وكانت أول وقف بالمدينة.
>
> Ibn Ishaq stated, "At Uhud, one of those killed was Mukhayriq. He was of Banu Tha'laba b. al-Fityawn. On the day of the battle of Uhud
> he proclaimed, 'O Jews, you have learned, I swear by God, that it is
> your duty to help Muhammad to victory.'
>
> They responded, 'But today is the sabbath.'  'You shall have no
> sabbath,' he insisted.
>
> He then took his sword and equipment saying, 'If I should fall, then
> my wealth goes to Muhammad to do with as he wishes.' He then went to
> the Messenger of God (SAAS), and fought along with him until he was
> killed.
>
> "The Messenger of God (SAAS) stated, so I have been told, 'Mukhayriq
> is the very best of the Jews.'"
>
> Al-Suhayli stated, "The Messenger of God (SAAS) converted Mukhayriq's
> property, consisting of seven orchards, into a *waqf*, a charitable
> endowment, in Media." Muhammad b. Ka'b al-Qurazi stated, "This was
> Medina's very first *waqf*".
>
> <sup>— [Al-Bidaya wa'l-Nihaya by Ibn Kathir](https://shamela.ws/book/4445/2699) --- [[English translation](https://archive.org/details/AlSiraAlNabawiyyaByIbnKathirAllVolumesInOnePdf/page/n897/mode/2up)]</sup>